# Message API in basecamp

Tags: php, curl, basecamp

Using PHP curl, i'm trying to post message from php application to basecamp. When i run this code, it returns the error like this

```
Hmm, that isn’t right
You may have typed the URL incorrectly.
Check to make sure you’ve got the spelling, capitalization, etc. exactly right.
```

Code

```
<?php

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$datastring = json_encode(array("name" => "from cURL"));

$URL = "https://basecamp.com/***/api/v1/projects/****.json";

   $ch = curl_init($URL);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastring);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
 echo $output;
?>
```

Not sure the API url is correct or not? How it can solve?

Comment: Use their support system https://basecamp.com/support

Answer (score 0):

The url doesn't look right - you'll want to check https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/messages.md#create-message and https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/comments.md#create-comment for adding a message or comment.

To add a new message to the project, you'd want

```
$URL = "https://basecamp.com/***/api/v1/projects/****/messages.json";
```

Comment: I checked the Post message with this url, but it returns the json like this {"status":"400","error":"Bad Request"}. How it can solve?